# Only iterate over a part of a Map

Tags: java, data-structures, indexing, hashmap, iteration

I have data stored in a HashMap, which I want to access via multiple threads simultaneously, to split the work done on the items.

Normally (with a List for example) I would just give each thread an index to start with and could easily split the work like this:

```
for(int i = startIndex; i < startIndex+batchSize && i < list.size(); i++)
{
    Item a = list.get(i);
    // do stuff with the Item
}
```

Of course this doesnt work with a HashMap, because I can't access it via an index.

Is there an easy way to iterate only over a part of the map? Should I rather use another data structure for this case?

I read about SortedMap, but it has too much overhead I dont need (sorting the items). I have a lot of data and performance is crucial.

Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How would you want the map partitioned?

Comment: Not sure I get the question. :) I would want the map partitioned into as many parts as the number of threads I have (8 for example). The partioning should not be a costly operation if possible in any way.

Comment: atm I am working with 100.000 entries, but its really open-ended. the algorithm should scale well with larger sizes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only do the traversal a few times, or if the map doesn't change you could get a Set of keys, and then send that to an array. From there its pretty much your normal method. But obviously if the HashMap changed then you would have to do those two operations over again which could get very costly.

Comment: Luckily the HashMap will not be changed by the threads. Your method sounds good, assuming that the toArray() method is cheap. Will give that a try and see how good the performance is, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you shouldn't be using a HashMap, because iteration order is undefined. Either use a `LinkedHashMap`, whose iteration order is the same as insertion order (at least it's defined), or use a `TreeMap`, whose iteration order is the natural sorting order. I would recommend the LinkedHashMap, because inserting an entry will make slicing the map up unpredictable.

To carve up a map, use this code:

```
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer,String>>(map.entrySet()).subList(start, end)) {
        Integer key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        // Do something with the entry
    }
```

I have in-lined the code, but expanded out it is equivalent to:

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> entryList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer,String>>();
entryList.addAll(map.entrySet());
entryList = entryList.subList(start, end); // You provide the start and end index
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : entryList) ...
```

Comment: TreeMap is not an option, because the ordering of the items would be a performancekiller, and i dont need a special order of the items. If the Map does not change while I work with it, should I still use LinkedHashMap? I dont care for the order of the items, so why is it important that it is defined?

Comment: Anywho, thanks for the solution with the entryList. Will compare it with Ross Larson's idea and see what performs quicker. :)

Comment: Because if you ask for items 1 to 5 in one thread, and item 6 to 10 in another, you could get the same item in both - the iteration order is not defined for hashmap (although it's probably fixed in reality - you could give it a try)

Comment: Already did, and it seemed to be fixed underneath. But you are right, undefined behaviour is never a good thing. LinkedHashMap it is!

Answer (score 1):

With HashMap#keySet -> Set#toArray you would get an array of the keys.

With this array you could procede as before, keep the array of keys and pass them to your threads. Then each thread would access only the keys it had been assigned and finally you could access the entries of a given partition of the HashMap with only those keys.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know before thinking about this problem either :) That's the great thing about SO - you learn so much when thinking about a problem. I was like "Hmm, what if Set had an toArray?" - checked the JavaDoc - and it has :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your map is enormous, the cost of iterating over a map is small compared with the cost of starting a task on another thread and trivial compared with the work you intend to do.

For this reason, the simplest way to divide up your work is likely to be turn the Map into an Array and break that up.

```
final Map<K, V> map =
final ExecutorServices es = 
final int portions = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
final Map.Entry<K,V>[] entries = (Map.Entry<K,V>[]) map.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[map.size()]);
final int portionSize = (map.size() + portions-1)/ portions;

for(int i = 0; i < portions; i++) {
    final int start = i * portionSize;
    final int end = Math.min(map.size(), (i + 1) * portionSize);
    es.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int j=start; j<end;j++) {
               Map.Entry<K,V> entry = entries[j];
               // process entry.
            }
        }
    });
}
```